# Build Object Hierarchy in Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hierarchy, custom-object

I'm losing quite some time copy-pasting identical properties and methods in various vba custom object I'm building. How do I create an custom-object hierarchy in VBA so one object and inherit properties and methods from others.

In python I would prob write something like:

> Class Car(Object)
>
> > whatever
>
> Class SlowCar(Car)
>
> > inherit whatever
>
> Class FastCar(Car)
>
> > inherit whatever

tks in advance.

Comment: Here you go: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2970 - its for VB6 but should be the same in VBA.

Comment: This also has what you need http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_interface_inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you're saying, this can be done via the Class Module.

1. From the VBA Editor, select Insert > Class Module
2. Change the name of the class Module to whatever you want (`Car` for
   example) via the Properties Window (press F4 to make it appear if it
   does not already)

Now that you've created your class module you can define its variables and/or properties. The example below would go into your `Car` Class Module creates a object that holds a car name and a speed

```
Private carName As String
Private carSpeed As Integer

' Car Name
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = carName 
End Property
Public Property Let Name(result As String)
    carName = result 
End Property 

' Car Speed
Public Property Get Speed() As Integer
    Speed = carSpeed
End Property
Public Property Let Speed(result As Integer)
    carSpeed = result 
End Property
```

Then from your Module, you can do the following

```
Sub CreateMyCars()
Dim slowCar as Car
Dim fastCar as Car

    Set slowCar = New Car
    Set fastCar = New Car

    slowCar.Name = "GoKart"
    slowCar.Speed = 35

    fastCar.Name = "Ferarri"
    fastCar.Speed = 185
End Sub
```

Comment: hmm, not quite Jaycal. SlowCar and FastCar are not instances of Car but object themselves. The thing is they would inherit whatever properties are built in Car plus what is added/overwritten. So one does not have to copy/paste 'whatever' is all sub-types of cars.

Comment: Well, I guess I didn't "understand what you're saying" :) You're speaking of some thing more like a Java interface, where a "FastCar" would automatically have all the methods and properties of a `Car`? (pardon my naivety...)

Answer (score 0):

VBA supports inheritance through the use of Interfaces, but they only "inherit" the signature of methods, not the implementation.

A way to reuse an object implementation would be through composition.

```
Class Car(Object)
    whatever

Class SlowCar(Car)
    Implements Car

    private mCar         as Car

    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        set mCar = new Car
    End Sub

    Private Sub Car_whatever
        Call mCar.whatever
    End Sub
```

And same for FastCar.